# ValueError: Shapes (None, 12, 2) and (None, 12) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

Can anybody help me, whats wrong with my shape. I am working on hierarchical text classification, there are total 12 classes i.e 3 catogeries and 9 sub categories. When i try to run LSTM on my data it works on 3 categories, but when I pass both categories. i.e both columns . I am facing this error.

```
Epoch 1/50
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-176-8c3ffb5351b5> in <module>
----> 1 LSTM_model.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs=50,batch_size=32)

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
   1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
   1099               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1100                 context.async_wait()

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    821       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    822       initializers = []
--> 823       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    824     finally:
    825       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    695     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    696         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 697             *args, **kwds))
    698 
    699     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2853       args, kwargs = None, None
   2854     with self._lock:
-> 2855       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2856     return graph_function
   2857 

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3211 
   3212       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3213       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3214       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3215       return graph_function, args, kwargs

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3073             arg_names=arg_names,
   3074             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3075             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3076         self._function_attributes,
   3077         function_spec=self.function_spec,

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    984         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    985 
--> 986       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    987 
    988       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    598         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    599         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 600         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    601     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    602 

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    971           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    972             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 973               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    974             else:
    975               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:749 train_step
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:204 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:149 __call__
        losses = ag_call(y_true, y_pred)
    D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:253 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:1535 categorical_crossentropy
        return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits)
    D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py:4687 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py:1134 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 12, 2) and (None, 12) are incompatible
```

The relevant code is :

```
LSTM_model=Sequential()
LSTM_model.add(LSTM(18,activation='relu',input_shape=X_train[0,:,:].shape))
LSTM_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
LSTM_model.add(Dense((12), activation='softmax'))
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
LSTM_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer=opt)
LSTM_model.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs=50,batch_size=32)
```

Here is shape of my data

```
X_train.shape
(42098, 20, 100)

y_train.shape
(42098, 12, 2)
```

Summary

```
LSTM_model.summary()
Model: "sequential_56"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_55 (LSTM)               (None, 18)                8568      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_54 (Dropout)         (None, 18)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_50 (Dense)             (None, 12)                228       
=================================================================
Total params: 8,796
Trainable params: 8,796
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: how did you obtain your y_train?

Comment: X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,test,test_size=0.25,random_state=0). I have passed my data into "X", and my labels into "test". @MarcoCerliani

Comment: No, how did you obtain your label? I didn't mean the split... they are in 3D so you make some manipulation to turn them into 3D

Comment: @MarcoCerliani yes i have used categorical function, test = to_categorical(label)

Comment: but to_categorical only one-hot them. what is label.shape before to_categorical?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani it is this (56131, 12)

Comment: This is a crucial point... I don't undestand why you one-hot encode them... they are 2D and seems ok (I don't know how this array is composed)

Comment: If i dont use to_categorical, i get very bad results, Epoch 1/50
1316/1316 [==============================] - 44s 34ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0616
Epoch 2/50
1316/1316 [==============================] - 43s 33ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0355
Epoch 3/50
1316/1316 [==============================] - 42s 32ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0355 0s - loss: nan - accura
Epoch 4/50
1316/1316 [==============================] - 43s 33ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0355 2
Epoch 5/50
1316/1316 [==============================] - 43s 33ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0355

Comment: how looks like this 2D label array? what does it contain?

Answer (score 0):

As you saw from the error message, the model expects a two-dimensional array as input, which second dimension's shape is 12. Since you have not provided a glimpse of the data you are dealing with, I am only speculating from now on. I think the third axis of your data is a one-hot representation of each of the 12 class values. If that is the case, you can convert the multi-dimensional one-hot representation to a one-dimensional representation using integer encoding. Once your third axis has a size of 1 (when you get an array with shape `(42098, 12, 1)`) you can reshape it to `(42098, 12)`.

In other words, you should get rid of the third dimension of your `y_train` variable. How you should do that depends on what your data is encoding.

Comment: Can you explain in detail, how should i solve this issue? "Shapes (None, 12, 2) and (None, 12) are incompatible". I have used categorical function which converts it into 3d, before that my shape of label is (56131, 12). If i dont use categorical function. I get these results Epoch 1/50
1316/1316 [==============================] - 44s 34ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0616
Epoch 2/50
1316/1316 [==============================] - 43s 33ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0355
Epoch 3/50
1316/1316 [==============================] - 42s 32ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0355
It remain same